# Add CoreData ObservableObject for Map?

Tags: swiftui, ios17

I have a problem with maps not updating. If the user enters a transaction, I save the map coordinates for where the transaction took place in coreData. I am also allowing the user to edit the transaction location. By tapping the Edit Location Save button the view returns to the detail view, but displays the "old" location. If I go back another level then return to the detail view the correct map is displayed.

I believe the problem is occurring because my coordinates are stored in coreData and doesn't have a @Published in an ObservableObject.

I tried saving off the coordinates for the return to the previous level but it didn't appear to be a very plausible solution.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Here is part of my SwiftData model showing the coordinates:

```
@Model class TravelEntries: Identifiable {

    var id: UUID
    var entryDate: Date
    var entryTimeZone: String
    var entryLat: Double
    var entryLong: Double
```

Start of logic to display detailed transaction information along with a map and a link to edit the location.

```
struct DetailView: View {

    var item: TravelEntries     <- coreData link

    @State private var mapType: Int = 0

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in

            VStack {
                if g.size.height > g.size.width {
                    DetailPortView(item: item, mapType: $mapType)
                } else {
                    DetailLandView(g: g, item: item, mapType: $mapType)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Transaction Details")
                    }
                }

                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {

                    NavigationLink {
                        EditLocation(g: g, item: item)

                    } label: {
                        Text("Edit Location")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(.darkGreen))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This logic displays the map:

```
struct DetailPortView: View {

    var item: TravelEntries

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: item.entryLat,
            longitude: item.entryLong
        )
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Map(initialPosition: .region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: (MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))))) {

                Marker("\(item.entryCatName) Expense", coordinate: coordinate)
                    .tint(.pink)
            }
            
            ShowDetails(item: item)
        }
    }
}
```

This code allows changing the map location.

```
struct EditLocation: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy

    var item: TravelEntries
    @ObservedObject private var lm = LocationManager()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @Environment(\.modelContext) var viewContext

    @State private var getStreet: String = ""
    @State private var getCity: String = ""
    @State private var getState: String = ""
    @State private var getCountry: String = ""
    @State private var getZipCode: String = ""
    @State private var invalidAddr: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ShowEntryDetails(g: g, item: item)
                
            ZStack {
                GetFormEntry(g: g, getStreet: $getStreet, getCity: $getCity, getState: $getState, getCountry: $getCountry, getZipCode: $getZipCode)
                    
            }
        }
        .alert("Invalid Address, Try Again", isPresented: $invalidAddr, actions: {})
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Edit Transaction Location")
                }
            }

            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {

                        // prep address string for conversion to coordinates
                        let locStr = getStreet + "," + getCity + "," + getState + " " + getCountry + " " + getZipCode

                        lm.getCoordinate(addressString: locStr) { coordinates, error  in

                            if error == nil {

                                // save coordinates to coreData
                                item.entryLat = coordinates.latitude
                                item.entryLong = coordinates.longitude

                                // copy data from form entry
                                item.entryLocCity = getCity
                                item.entryLocState = getState
                                item.entryLocCountry = getCountry

                            dismiss()

                        } else {
                            // Invalid address-- try again
                            invalidAddr = true

                            getStreet = ""
                            getCity = ""
                            getState = ""
                            getCountry = ""
                            getZipCode = ""
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text ("Save")
                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `@Bindable var item: TravelEntries`

Comment: @workingdog support: I researched using Bindable but still not sure how to implement it. I did try placing Bindable var item: TravelEntries at the top of DetailView and EditLocation structures (one at a time and removing the current var item: TravelEntries) without any noticeable change in the map update.